# What does '0' do in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find the product of all digits in a number, which I have stored as a string (due to int and long length limits).

So the number looks like this:

```
final String number = "1234567898765432123......etc"
```

If I use this code, it works:

```
product *= number.charAt(i + j) - '0';
```

It doesn't if I remove the '0'.

I got this code from another online resource. Can someone explain what the '0' does?

Comment: those ascii chars can be casted to integers. these are indices on the ascii table so check that and get a 2nd thought about it I think you will get it ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ascii characters are actually numbers. And `0 .. 9` digits are numbers starting from decimal 48 (0x30 hexadecimal).

```
'0' is 48
'1' is 49
...
'9' is 57
```

So to get the value of any character digit, you can just remove the '0', ie 48.

```
'1' - '0' => 1
 49 -  48 => 1
```

If you don't remove '0' (48) the total sum will be over by `48 * numberOfDigits`.

See an [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) to locate digits in it.

Note that `'0'` is the character `0`, not the string `"0"` containing the character `'0'`.

Answer (score 10):

Let's check the ASCII chart [image]

You can see the Dec value of '0' -> '9'

The charAt() method just gets the character, is automatically converted to int value when calculating.

```
'0' -> 48
'1' -> 49
...
'9' -> 57
```

after minus '0':

```
'0' - '0' -> 48 - 48 = 0
'1' - '0' -> 49 - 48 = 1
...
'9' - '0' -> 57 - 48 = 9
```

After all, **'n' - '0' = n** with n is a digit character

Answer (score 4):

Removing `0` from `number.charAt(i + j)` will give you same character in form of digit (or `integer`).

When you are using character in any expression that character is replaced by its `ASCII` values.

ASCII value for `'0'`(character 0) is 48
ASCII value for `'1'`(character 0) is 49

Now, if `number.charAt(i + j)` is `'1'` then in your expression `'1'` is replaced by 49 and `'0'` is replaced by 48 which will give you `1`(`integer`) as a result.

Answer (score 2):

'0' is the char value of zero.

When you write a string, you're writing an array of 'char' datatypes which the compiler translates into ASCII values (which have a corresponding decimal number value).

When you call

```
number.charAt(i + j);
```

You are actually generating an ASCII value.

http://www.asciitable.com/

The ASCII value of '0' is:

48

'1':

49

.
.
.

'9':

57

So when you call

```
number.charAt(i + j) - '0';
```

You're actually running the operation of an ASCII value minus 48 which is it's actual value as an integer.

e.g.

('9' - '0') = (57 - 48) = (9 - 0) = 9

Answer (score 1):

Characters and integers are practically the same thing because every character has a code (ASCII, but also Unicode in some contexts).

By subtracting `'0'` from whatever number is in the string, you get the actual value of that integer.

```
'0' > 48
48 - 48 = 0 (integer value)
```

The same applies to all the other integers. You can do similar things with other characters, such as `letter - 'A'` to assign a number to every letter based on its position in the alphabet.

Answer (score 1):

Characters are stored as numbers. 
For example, '0' equals 48 in ASCII. So if you want to convert a character into an integer, you have to remove '0' (or remove 48 would work the same way):

```
product *= number.charAt(i + j) - 48;
```

More information: http://www.asciitable.com