# Getting the second digit from a long variable

Tags: java, long-integer

I am trying to fetch second digit from a long variable.

```
long mi = 110000000;
int firstDigit = 0;
String numStr = Long.toString(mi);
for (int i = 0; i < numStr.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println("" + i + " " + numStr.charAt(i));
    firstDigit =  numStr.charAt(1);
}
```

When I am printing `firstDigit =  numStr.charAt(1)` on console. I am getting `1` which is expected but when the loop finishes `firstDigit` has `49`.
Little confused why.

Comment: Why do you need a loop if you only want the second digit?

Comment: Second digit in which calculation system? Hexadecimal, decimal, octal, binary, ...?

Comment: Related: [What does '0' do in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34409950)

Comment: Whenever I asked a question that gets marked as duplicate, I am downvoted left, right and center (and of course down). Then, how did this one get nine upvotes?

Comment: You appear to be starting with a `long` variable? Why make it into a string?

Comment: Your code returns 49 because it's wrong. Once you'll have it fixed, the correct answer will be returned, and it will likely be [42](https://www.google.it/search?q=the+answer+to+life+the+universe+and+everything).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You got confused because 49 is ASCII value of integer 1. So you may parse character to integer then you can see integer value.

```
    Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mi).charAt(1)):
```

Comment: to prevent `The method parseInt(String) in the type Integer is not applicable for the arguments (char)` you should use something like `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mi).charAt(1)+"");`

Answer (score 14):

Because 49 is the ASCII value of char   '1'.

So you should not assign a char to int directly.

And you don't need a loop here which keeps ovveriding the current value with `charAt(1)` anyway.

```
int number = numStr.charAt(1) - '0'; // substracting ASCII start value
```

The above statement internally works like 49 -48 and gives you 1.

If you feel like that is confusious, as others stated use `Character.getNumericValue();`

Or, although I don't like `""+` hack, below should work

```
int secondDigit = Integer.parseInt("" + String.valueOf(mi).charAt(1));
```

Answer (score 5):

You're probably looking for `Character.getNumericValue(...)` i.e.

```
firstDigit = Character.getNumericValue(numStr.charAt(1));
```

Otherwise, as the variable `firstDigit` is of type `int` that means you're assigning the [ASCII representation of the character '1'](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html) which is 49 rather than the integer at the specified index.

Also, note that since you're interested in only a particular digit there is no need to put the statement `firstDigit = numStr.charAt(1);` inside the loop.

rather, just do the following outside the loop.

```
int number = Character.getNumericValue(numStr.charAt(1));
```

Answer (score 3):

you only need define firstDigit as a char type variable, so will print as character.
since you define as int variable, it's value is the ASCII value of char '1': 49. this is why you get 49 instead of 1.

Answer (score 3):

the answer `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mi).charAt(1)+"");` is correct.

However, **if we want to consider performace** in our program, we need some improvements.

We have to time consuming methods, `Integer.parseInt()` and `String.valueOf()`. And always a custom methods is much faster than `Integer.parseInt()` and `String.valueOf()`. see [simple benchmarks](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2009/08/java_tip_how_parse_integers_quickly).

So, high performance solution can be like below:

```
int y=0;
while (mi>10)
{
    y=(int) (mi%10);
    mi=mi/10;
}
System.out.println("Answer is: " + y);
```

to test it:

```
long mi=4642345432634278834L;
int y=0;

long start = System.nanoTime();

//first solution
//y=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(mi).charAt(1)+"");      

//seconf solution
while (mi>10)
{
    y=(int) (mi%10);
    mi=mi/10;
}

long finish = System.nanoTime();

long d = finish - start;
System.out.println("Answer is: " + y + " , Used time: " + d);

//about 821 to 1232 for while in 10 runs
//about 61225 to 76687 for parseInt in 10 runs
```

Comment: If we want to consider performance we definitely should go with `(num / 10^{Log_10{num} - 1}) % 10` instead of that loop. Which is much, much faster than the other alternatives, but not exactly obvious on first glance for most people I'd wager.

Comment: There is not `^` function in java (just for Bit operation ), we should use `Pow()` method, in this case we should use `parseInt()` and other conversions. They are so time consuming in java.

Comment: That's not supposed to be actual Java code, more LaTeX to write the mathematical formula.

Comment: @Voo Completely wrong. Log10 and/or 10^ are elegant, but numerically *extremely expensive floating-point functions*. They are also not 100% accurate because of floating-point rounding.

Answer (score 3):

Doing string manipulation to work with numbers is almost always the wrong approach.

To get the second digit use the following;

```
int digitnum = 2;

int length = (int)Math.log10(mi));
int digit = (int)((mi/Math.pow(base,length-digitnum+1))%base);
```

If you want a different digit than the second change digitnum.

To avoid uncertainty with regards to floating point numbers you can use a integer math library like guavas [IntMath](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/math/IntMath.html)

Comment: While the mathematically correct answer, I'll admit that I couldn't prove that this gives the correct answer when considering float inaccuracies off the cuff.

Comment: @Voo Answer updated to just use log10, with reference to guava for pure int base alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look

```
System.out.println(numStr.charAt(1));
firstDigit =  numStr.charAt(1);
System.out.println(firstDigit);
```

The result wouldn't be the same you will get

```
1
49
```

This happens because your **firstDigit** is **int**. Change it to **char** and you will get expected result

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like below,

```
firstDigit = Integer.parseInt( numStr.charAt(1)+"");
```

So it will print second digit from long number.

Answer (score 1):

Some things which have not been mentioned yet:

- The second digit for integer datatypes is **undefined** if the long number is 0-9 (No, it is not zero. Integers do not have decimal places, this is only correct for floating-point numbers. Even then you must return **undefined** for NaN or an infinity value). In this case you should return a sentinel like e.g. -1 to indicate that there is no second digit.
- Using log10 to get specific digits looks elegant, but they are 1. one of the numerically most expensive functions and 2. do often give incorrect results in edge cases. I will give some counterexamples later.

Performance could be improved further:

```
public static int getSecondDigit(long value) {
long tmp = value >= 0 ? value : -value;
if (tmp < 10) {
  return -1;
}

long    bigNumber = 1000000000000000000L;
boolean isBig     = value >= bigNumber;

long  decrement   = isBig ? 100000000000000000L : 1;
long  firstDigit  = isBig ? bigNumber : 10;
int   result      = 0;
if (!isBig) {
  long test = 100;

  while (true) {
    if (test > value) {
      break;
    }
    decrement = firstDigit;
    firstDigit = test;
    test *= 10;
  }
}



// Remove first
while (tmp >= firstDigit) {
  tmp -= firstDigit;
}

// Count second
while (tmp >= decrement) {
  tmp -= decrement;
  result++;
}

return result;
}
```

Comparison:
1 000 000 random longs

String.valueOf()/Character.getNumericValue(): 106 ms
Log/Pow by Taemyr: 151 ms
Div10 by @Gholamali-Irani: 45 ms
Routine above: 30 ms

This is not the end, it can be even faster by lookup tables
decrementing 1/2/4/8, 10/20/40/80 and avoid the use of multiplication.

Comment: very good comparison

Answer (score 0):

try this to get second char of your long

```
mi.toString().charAt(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **How to get ASCII code**

```
int ascii = 'A';
int ascii = 'a';
```

So if you assign a character to an integer, the integer will be holding the `ASCII` value of that character. Here I explicitly gave the values, in your code you are calling a method that returns a character, that's why you are getting `ASCII` instead of digit.